# How Implement an auto-refresh module with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, timeago

Well, I'm beginning with Angularjs, so I can be appropriately not clean with my question.

I'm using a module called ngtimeago (below), and I'm trying to make a auto-refresh, to update all `{{date | timeago}}`

How can I use a existent .filter() to make a global refresh?

```js
 'use strict';
 var catalyst = angular.module('ngtimeago', []);
catalyst.filter('timeago', function($timeout) {
        return function(input, p_allowFuture) {
              var substitute = function (stringOrFunction, number, strings) {
                    var string = angular.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, dateDifference) : stringOrFunction;
                    var value = (strings.numbers && strings.numbers[number]) || number;
                    return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
                },
                nowTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
                date = (new Date(input)).getTime(),
                refreshMillis= 6e4, //A minute
                allowFuture = p_allowFuture || false,
                strings= {
                     prefixAgo: '',
                    prefixFromNow: '',
                    suffixAgo: "ago",
                    suffixFromNow: "from now",
                    seconds: "%d seconds",
                    minute: "about a minute",
                    minutes: "%d minutes",
                    hour: "about an hour",
                    hours: "about %d hours",
                    day: "a day",
                    days: "%d days",
                    month: "about a month",
                    months: "%d months",
                    year: "about a year",
                    years: "%d years"
                },
                dateDifference = nowTime - date,
                words,
                seconds = Math.abs(dateDifference) / 1000,
                minutes = seconds / 60,
                hours = minutes / 60,
                days = hours / 24,
                years = days / 365,
                separator = strings.wordSeparator === undefined ?  " " : strings.wordSeparator,
                prefix = strings.prefixAgo,
                suffix = strings.suffixAgo;
                            if (allowFuture) {
                if (dateDifference < 0) {
                    prefix = strings.prefixFromNow;
                    suffix = strings.suffixFromNow;
                }
            }
            words = seconds < 45 && substitute(strings.seconds, Math.round(seconds), strings) ||
            seconds < 90 && substitute(strings.minute, 1, strings) ||
            minutes < 45 && substitute(strings.minutes, Math.round(minutes), strings) ||
            minutes < 90 && substitute(strings.hour, 1, strings) ||
            hours < 24 && substitute(strings.hours, Math.round(hours), strings) ||
            hours < 42 && substitute(strings.day, 1, strings) ||
            days < 30 && substitute(strings.days, Math.round(days), strings) ||
            days < 45 && substitute(strings.month, 1, strings) ||
            days < 365 && substitute(strings.months, Math.round(days / 30), strings) ||
            years < 1.5 && substitute(strings.year, 1, strings) ||
            substitute(strings.years, Math.round(years), strings);
  //   console.log(prefix+words+suffix+separator);
   prefix.replace(/ /g, '')
   words.replace(/ /g, '')
   suffix.replace(/ /g, '')
   return (prefix+' '+words+' '+suffix+' '+separator);
             };
    var refreshDates = function () {
        $timeout(refreshDates, 3000);
    console.log("Atualizando datas...");
   // $filter('timeago').reload();
    };
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      
   angular.module('App',['ngtimeago']).controller('TestTimeago', function($scope){

          $scope.listTest = [];
var tomorrow = new Date();

        $scope.test1 = { 
       "date": Date.now()
        }
       $scope.test2 = { 
       "date": tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() -0.002)

        }
      $scope.listTest.push($scope.test1);
      $scope.listTest.push($scope.test2);
        
  });
 
   </script>
      <body ng-controller="TestTimeago">
             <ul>    
                 <li ng-repeat='time in listTest'>
                      <p>{{ time.date | timeago}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </body>
```

Comment: Ps: I'm trying it, about 3 or 4 hours

Comment: what you are trying to do when you say auto refresh? am not getting  your question.

Comment: do you want to update the time in real time ?

Comment: yes, I want to do a auto-refresh like:

var refreshDates = function() {
    $timeout(refreshDates, 30000);
};
refreshDates();